# Change xml element name before serialization

Tags: c#, xml

I have a built a series of classes to create a SEPA XML file.
Each class is essentially a 'ROOT' with its elements serialized with [XmlElement("NAME")]

One of my classes is named 'OrgId' for the OrgId element of the same name you see in the below XML

```
<GrpHdr>
  <MsgId>0000001XXXXXXX</MsgId>
  <CreDtTm>2014-04-30T15:08:04</CreDtTm>
  <NbOfTxs>100</NbOfTxs>
  <CtrlSum>500.00</CtrlSum>
  <InitgPty>
    <Id>
      <OrgId>
        <Othr>
          <Id>IE01XXX999999</Id>
        </Othr>
      </OrgId>
    </Id>
  </InitgPty>
</GrpHdr>
```

So once I have updated all my values and am ready to serialize my classes as a complete
XML document I write the file to the harddrive using the following code :

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SEPABuilder.DefaultFileSection.Document));

        try
        {
            using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Xml.txt"))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, doc, namespaces);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // DO SOMETHING WITH EXCEPTION
        }
```

However, if I want to change this element name from 'OrgId' to 'PrvtId' how can i do this?

I tried inheriting a base class but the serialization wouldnt work with inherited classes.
I then looked into this and I tried putting [XmlType("NAME OF BASE CLASS")] above the deriving classes but this didnt work.

I also thought about having a copy of the classes that make up the xml document and use 
a different namespace name for each but thats not correct at all and would just cause 
more and more unecessary work.

I was wondering is there any way of changing an element name based on a condition, before
the serialization takes place and the class is saved as an XML file to my hard-drive?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well, this is the UGLY answer, but you can always Serialize to a string instead, and then replace the tags in the string based on your condition. But this is the ugly way of doing it.

In my experience, when you specify a "special" name for the XMLElement using [XmlElement("Name")], the deserializer is supposed to pick that up and deserialize properly back into the property properly.